# Is it safe to make a Unique Index the Primary Key?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, change-tracking

I have a vendor database that I want to use Change Data Tracking against but cannot because none of their tables have Primary Keys defined.  The tables do have Unique Indexes but they are not defined as PK Constraints.  It seems to me that making them Primary Keys would be a safe thing to do (i.e. will not interfere with or change the software operation) given that they are already Unique Indexes.

Can anyone tell me if my understanding is correct or if I am missing something?

Comment: Safe is kind of vague. Is it possible? Yeah, since the PK needs to be unique by definition. Is it a good idea? It depends. How many columns are you talking about and what data types are they?

Comment: Assuming the columns don't allow NULLs, you should check with your vendor since they manage the schema. Changing the index to a PK will change error messages on dups that they might be looking for.

Comment: The unique indexes are all on a single Numeric(9,0) column set to AutoIncrement Identity.  Thanks for the thought on the error returns possibly changing.  Ill have to test on that a bit

Comment: To Dan's point, also make sure they're OK with you doing this **and** using change data tracking - you might be voiding support by modifying the database.

Comment: "... because none of their tables have Primary Keys defined" - GET RID of that vendor IMMEDIATELY!

Comment: @Vérace why? OP says all the tables have UNIQUE constraints, which they are not much different than PK constraints.

Comment: I've had bad experiences in the past with systems which were "customised" and/or "optimised" and/or `<other_bs_marketing_term>` which didn't have PKs and/or FKs. Mostly it appears (at least to me) to be some sort of legacy issue stretching back into the midsts of time where some storage systems didn't support PKs and/or FKs or (what I consider to be) other important features. If, in 2017, your database doesn't have PKs, then something is wrong! I can overlook them on small mickey-mouse lookups (i.e. a "salutation" table with 10 entries) where it will always be more efficient to perform a FTS.

Comment: I once worked on a system that was the asset management system for a **huge** public utility in a wealthy EU country (on Oracle). I did a query to look for FKs - none! Thinking the problem was me, I asked senior colleague. He, almost with pride, said there were none... start of my problems with working for that entity! DB was a mess with more holes than a Swiss cheese. Once bitten, twice shy!

Answer (score 5):

No it's not safe.

From a query perspective it might look OK, but if you don't know how the application handles primary keys you shouldn't change that without checking with the vendor first.

You could break their error handling, their future update scripts etc.

Just to give you an example, during a future upgrade they may want to change some tables where you added CDC and they will receive an error. What does your contract say about support in that case?

If you are using a vendor database it's up to them to support it. If you go around making changes you are basically putting your system in a state they never tested so they would (rightfully so) probably tell you you have an unsupported configuration when things go wrong.

We don't know what application or vendor you are talking about, but if it doesn't support customizations you probably shouldn't customize the database without asking them first.